# Mathematica Internal Self Test Error winFonts|c|310

Tags: warning-messages

Every time I open Mathematica, I get two identical error messages:
`INTERNAL SELF-TEST ERROR: winFonts|c|310
Click here to find out if this problem is known, and to help improve
the Wolfram System by reporting it to Wolfram Research.`
I am using Mathematica 10.2, but I tried uninstalling it, reinstalling 10.1 and still this error appears. This causes some text in the notebook to be replaced by squares, mostly the square brackets. Any idea of why this happens?

Comment: Have you tried [this tip](http://support.wolfram.com/kb/12464)?

Comment: Thank you, but this did not work. I had to input my activation key again and I don't see how, but could it be that there is a problem with the key?

Comment: If there's a problem with the key, it would just ask you again to enter a key.  Try asking Wolfram Support.